# How to add a claim in the bearer send by httpinterceptor of adal-angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, owin, adal

In a angularjs application, i use adal and adal-angular libraries to authentify user on Azure AD. On backend I use OWIN middleware in my webAPI to add custom claims with :

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
        {
            if(!context.IsValidated)
                return;

            var userManager = context.OwinContext.Get<UserManager>();
            string email = context.Ticket.Identity.GetClaimValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email);
            User user = userManager.GetByEmail(email);

            context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserId, user.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }
});
```

It's work for the current request, but how to add the claim in the bearer send by httpinterceptor of adal-angular for the next requests?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this won't work since the token is signed from your trusted Identity Provider and you will not be able to change it within the client?

Comment: I just want to send a customized bearer from the client instead of adding the claim on each request. I want to add the claim only on the first request after authentification and include it in the bearer

Comment: I know, but I think and hope that this is not possible. @juunas Can you confirm this?

Comment: Why do you hope that is not possible? due to security issue?

Comment: Yes, for security reasons. If a client is able to manipulate claims, I can't trust them anymore.

Comment: Agree with @MartinBrandl 1000%, you cannot do that (hope nobody will never be able to do that either). This is intrinsic to [JWT](https://jwt.io/).

Answer (score 3):

To answer your direct question: you cannot modify the access token, period.
It has a digital signature which will no longer be valid if you change anything in the token.
It's a security measure that prevents tampering.
Your OWIN middleware downloads the public keys of the signing key pairs from Azure AD on startup, and uses those to validate tokens.

Now if you stored your internal ids as extension attributes,
it would actually be possible to tell Azure AD to include that in the tokens.
This feature is in preview though, and not recommended for production use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-custom-claims-via-directory-extensions.
Here you would set the internal id as an extension on the User entity, and have it included for access tokens to your API.

A pragmatic solution to your issue might be an in-memory cache.
How often do emails change?

Comment: Thanks for confirming

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time and explanations. Emails never change. I have also an AuthorizationServer for a simple login/password authentication. Could i redirect Azure AD authentication on this authorization server to generate another token with the user id?

Comment: @juunas Could you have a look to my answer and tell me if it's a good way to change the identity from Azure AD to identity of application? Thanks for your help